# What is the best way to make the data as stationary & inverse transform in time series - Python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series, regression

I did the 1st differencing as the time series is not stationary.
When I do the invert transformation, some values are coming as negative as we get negative values due to diff(). Is there a way to sort it out and bring back the data in original format as close to the expected result.

This is my python code. Is there a way to fix the code or any alternate logic to make the data as stationary and forecasting the series?

```
count = 0

def invert_transformation(df_train, df_forecast):
    """Revert back the differencing to get the forecast to original scale."""
    df_fc = df_forecast.copy()
    columns = df_train.columns
    if count > 0:      # For 1st differencing 
        print("Enter into invert transformation")
        for col in columns:        
            df_fc[str(col)+'_f'] = df_train[col].iloc[-1] + df_fc[str(col)+'_f'].cumsum()  
        print("df_fc: \n", df_fc)    
        return df_fc

# Since the data is not stationary, I did the 1st difference
df_differenced = df_train.diff().dropna()
count = count + 1 #increase the count
count

....
....
model = VAR(df_differenced)
....
fc = model_fitted.forecast(y=forecast_input, steps=10)

df_forecast2 = pd.DataFrame(fc, index=df2.index[-nobs:], columns=df2.columns + '_f')

df_results = invert_transformation(df_train, df_forecast2)
```

value of df_results(TS is the index column) are:

```
TS       Field1_f        Field2_f
44:13.0  6.826511e+05    1.198614e+06
44:14.0  -8.620101e+05   4.694556e+05
..
..
44:22.0  -1.401620e+07   -2.092826e+06
```

Value of df_differenced are:

```
TS      Field1      Field2
43:34.0 187000.0    29000.0
43:35.0 175000.0    76722.0
43:36.0 -10000.0    31000.0
43:37.0 90000.0     42000.0
43:38.0 -130000.0   -42000.0
43:39.0 40000.0     -98444.0
..
..
44:11.0 -130000.0   40722.0
44:12.0 117000.0    -42444.0
```